# How does life-steal work in the original Diablo?

Tags: diablo

I've been recently playing the original Diablo, since back when I was a kid I didn't appreciate it as much as it deserved. Knowledge from later Diablo games helped a lot.

I have been having trouble with life-steal. I am playing a rogue and I've been using [The Undead Crown](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/The_Undead_Crown) which is dropped by the skeleton king.

The wiki says it gives me 5% life steal. At that time, my damage was ~5-10 so I assumed the 5% got rounded to zero. However, now that my damage is ~20-40. I still see no life gained from the crown.

My question is, how is the life-steal supposed to work? Is it only noticeable with really high damages? Is it broken?

Comment: Can't find anything in Jarulf's guide that would make this apply. =/ I'd make sure you've updated to the most recent version of the game, you'll have to do this manually here: https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-patch-information

Comment: @decency, yes I had updated to 1.09b which is the latest patch.

Comment: What process are you using to determine your not gaining any life?

Comment: @Ramhound One was to open the character page, hit multiple targets, multiple times and see that my life doesn't increase. I did that many times. Another thing I did many times was to note my health, hit many targets without taking a hit and checking my life again, which was unchanged.

Comment: My only thought is that lifesteal doesn't work with ranged weapons, but I'm not sure if that's the case for certain.

Comment: @decency, I haven't played with the other characters. You may be right.

Comment: You can try equipping a melee weapon with the Rogue and testing.

Comment: Life Steal can be less effective against certain types of enemy, and some enemies can be completely immune to the effect - if you've been testing on the same group of enemies/same enemy type then it would be worth checking against some other type of mob.

Comment: @pixel, I had tried with many types of enemies. The fact that by the end of the (single player) game, I couldn't get a single hit point from life-leech is a bit too suspicious. Most probably, Decency is right in saying that life-steal only works with melee weapons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be using a bow.  You can't steal life with them even if the life steal comes from another item (your Crown).

Source: http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/D1_Modifiers#.25_Steal_Life

Comment: This is question is related to the original Diablo, ie: Diablo 1.

Comment: Edited and included info about D1.